# Control task run in background node.js

Tags: node.js, message-queue, task-queue

I am writing an application with node.js about using Twitter api.
function like below:

```
app.get('/api/get_follower', function(req, res){
    var username = req.query.username
    var client =  new twitter({
        consumer_key: global.twitter_consumer_key,
        consumer_secret: global.twitter_consumer_secret,
        access_token_key: global.token_access,
        access_token_secret: global.token_secret
    });

    check_username(username)
    .then(function(data){
        res.status(200).end()

        // this code below will run in background.
        // I want to follow it and it will throw to me if error or inform me when success
        // and if server will be crashed, it will run continue from that time (if can)
        return get_followers(client, -1, [])

    }, function(err){
        res.statusMessage = 'user not found'
        res.status(404).end()
    })

})

var check_username = function(req, res){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        client.get(link, function(err, data){
            if(err){
                reject(err)
            }else{
                resolve(data)
            }
        })
    })
}

var get_followers = function(client, cursor, data){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        client.get(link, function(err, _data){
            if(err){
                setTimeout(function() {
                    get_followers(client, cursor, data)
                }, 30000);
            }else{
                var data = data.concat(_data.users)
                if(_data.next_cursor != 0){
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        get_followers(client, _data.next_cursor, data)
                    }, 30000);
                }else{
                    resolve(data)
                }
            }
        })
    })
}
```

Func get_followers will take more time to complete, so I want to run it in background, client don't care about it, only check username and response for them. But I want to follow the task run in background, if fail or success will inform me (console...). And if have many request to my router at the same time, will be not effected to performance...

I have find out "queue" module but don't know how to apply it with my case (get_followers).

Please help ! Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

If it takes that long the client request will time out.  You will need to add a status/result route that the client can poll.

Also I recommend creating a separate module for checkusername getfollowers etc. which the status route can call. And using `async/await` and arrow syntax will make code cleaner.

Comment: client don't need to follow it, only me in backend want to know. get_followers func run background and I will following it by console or anything..